# If $X$ is a singular matrix, then is $X'X$ singular?

Tags: matrices

If $X$ is a singular matrix, then is $X'X$ singular? And why?

(**'** means transpose)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are your thoughts? In this case it might help to explore equivalent conditions to singularity of a matrix.

Answer (score 5):

$Xv=0$ implies $X^T X v = 0$.

$X^T X v = 0$ implies $v^T X^T X v = \|X v\|^2 = 0$, which in turn implies $X v=0$.

Answer (score 4):

Note that $rank(X'X)\leq\min\{rank(X'),rank(X)\}<n$, which implies $X'X$ is still singular.

Answer (score 2):

We know that a matrix is sigular is equivalent to the determinant being zero. Therefore from your statement we have $\det(X)=0$. We also know $$\det(X^{\prime})=\det(X),$$ and $$\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B).$$ So we have $$\det(XX^{\prime})=\det(X)\det(X^{\prime})=0.$$ Which is equivalent to saying $XX^{\prime}$ is singular.

Comment: For a discussion on the $\det$ properties please refer http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Since $X$ is singular, there exists a non-zero vector $v$ such that $Xv=0$.

Now,
$$X^TXv=X^T(Xv)=X^T0=0,$$
which implies $v$ is also in the nullspace of $X^TX$. Thus, the matrix is singular.

Comment: Forgive the naivety, but isn't matrix multiplication noncommutative?  And hence (') will not necessarily equal '(), right?  I feel like I must be missing something, because I know your conclusion is correct.  But I feel commutativity is necessary to say that your algebra implies " is also in the nullspace of '".

Comment: @kdbanman Yes. It’s non-commutative, but it is associative. So $AB\neq BA$, but $(AB)C=A(BC)$.

Comment: I... am not clever.  Thank you.  The property I was looking for was indeed associativity, which matrix multiplication definitely has.

Answer (score 2):

$X \, \text{is singular} \Leftrightarrow \det(X) = 0, \tag{1}$

$\det (X) = 0 \Rightarrow \det (X^TX) = \det (X^T) \det (X) = 0, \tag{2}$

$\det (X^TX) = 0 \Rightarrow X^TX \text{is singular}; \tag{3}$

***OR***

one might observe that $X$ singular implies the existence of a vector $v \ne 0$
such that $Xv = 0$, whence $X^TXv = 0$, whence $X^TX$ is singular!  QED.

Hope this helps!  Cheerio,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***