# Why the transpose of a singular matrix is singular?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have to prove this lemma without using the concept of rank neither the concept of determinant:

> $A$ is a singular matrix iff $A^T$ is singular

Unfortunately i've only found proofs that contains rank and determinant. Can you help me ?

Comment: What's your definition of singular matrix?

Comment: A singular matrix is one that is invertible?

Comment: To me, singular matrix = Columns are linear dipendent. I want to prove that that if columns are linear dipendent also rows are.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If $X$ is a singular matrix, then is $X'X$ singular?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/526797/if-x-is-a-singular-matrix-then-is-xx-singular)

Comment: $\det A=\det A^T$.

Comment: @Sorfosh Singular matrices are **not** invertible.

Comment: For a proof using the definition you mentioned above, have a look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/173156/are-a-square-matrixs-columns-and-rows-either-bothseparately-linearly-independ).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Assume for contradiction that $A^T$ was invertible, then there would be a matrix $B$ with $BA^T=I$. But that means $I=I^T=(BA^T)^T=AB^T$, so $B^T$ would be an inverse for $A$, which is impossible.

Answer (score 5):

Formally, a singular matrix $A$ is one for which *there* does not exist another matrix $B$ with $AB=BA=I$.

The statement here can be proven through the contrapositive: if $A$ is not singular, there exists some $B$ with $AB=I$. Transposing this gives $B^TA^T=I$, so $A^T$ is not singular. Thus if $A^T$ is singular, $A$ is singular. Replacing $A$ with $A^T$ in the last sentence gives the other direction, so the original statement is established.

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ were singular, then the kernel (null space) of $A$ has nonzero vectors in it. That is, $Ax = 0$ admits nontrivial (nonzero) solutions. Now take the transpose on each side. Then if $x$ is nonzero, so is $x^T$ (clearly), and so $x^T A^T = 0^T$ also admits nonzero solutions, so $A^T$ is singular.

Comment: How do you know that $x^TA^T=0$, $x\ne0$ implies that there exists $y\ne0$ with $A^Ty=0$?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Sean Roberson did not directly claim that. If $x^TA^T=0^T$ has a nontrivial solution, then clearly its rows are not linearly independent, so it is singular.

Comment: @Acccumulation We need a definition. His definition of singular seems to be non-zero kernel. Which says exactly that the columns are dependent. Now saying rows dependent implies singular is just assuming what we 're supposedly proving, that the transpose of a singular matrix is singular.